# Android notification lifecycle

Tags: android, notifications, lifecycle

In my app I have notifications which can be showed when application is not running. When I open and close application, notifications disappear.

Is it normal situation? Is there any method to keep notifications?

Comment: "When I open and close application" -- please explain, **in detail**, what you mean by this. "Is it normal situation?" -- no.

Comment: Normally, notifications you create, stay until you cancel them.

Comment: @CommonsWare Service in background builds notification. It appears on the screen. Then I open application and force close it. After that notification disappear.

Comment: "force close it" -- please explain, **in detail**, what you mean by this.

Comment: @CommonsWare I press overview system button and remove my application from the list.

Comment: On most devices, that terminates your process and destroys any running components (e.g., services).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that there is no any other service or project module, which does the following call NotificationManager.cancelAll() to cancel all the notifications. It is always better to keep the notifications controller over Unique ID and cancel only the notifications which are related to that part, by this the code won't touch the notifications posted by other project parts.

For more reference follow Notification Manager:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html

Comment: Thank you very much! In onCreate() method there was a code, which removes all notifications.